# how to overcome overlapping in multirow in latex

Tags: multirow, overlap

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[p]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{\large Ranking results for alternatives}
        \label{indices}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Alternative&Value of $\lambda,\mu,\nu$& Value Index&Ambiguity Index&Ranking Order  \\
                        \hline
                        
                        \multirow{1}[10]{1in}{\centering\textit{A}\\\textit{B}\\\textit{C}}&$\lambda=0.10,\mu=0.40,\nu=0.50$&\multirow{1}{1in} {\centering$0.5450$\\$0.6451$\\$0.6035$}&\multirow{1}{1in}{\centering$0.5450$\\$0.6451$\\$0.6035$}&$B>C>A$\\
                        
                        \cline{1-5}
                        
                        \multirow{1}{1in}{\centering\textit{A}\\\textit{B}\\\textit{C}}&$\lambda=0.10,\mu=0.40,\nu=0.50$&\multirow{1}{1in} {\centering$0.5450$\\$0.6451$\\$0.6035$}&\multirow{1}{1in}{\centering$0.5450$\\$0.6451$\\$0.6035$}&$B>C>A$\\
                        \hline
                                        
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

[image: outcome of above coding]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Any news? Does no answer solve your problem? So far I didn't see that you upvote or accept any answer you got.

Comment: got the solution. Thanks

Comment: If the problem is solved then please accept/upvote the provided answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three versions of the table. The first one uses no `\multirow` as all, the second used `\multirow`, the third one nested tabulars. All three outputs look like the following screenshot:

[image]

If you want some more vertical white space between the individual lines, you can make use of the `cellspace` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[p]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Ranking results for alternatives}
        \label{indices}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Alternative&Value of $\lambda,\mu,\nu$& Value Index&Ambiguity Index&Ranking Order  \\
                        \hline

                        \textit{A} &                                        & 0.5450 & 0.5450 &  \\
                        \textit{B} & $\lambda=0.10$, $\mu=0.40$, $\nu=0.50$ & 0.6451 & 0.6451 & $B>C>A$ \\
                        \textit{C} &                                        & 0.6035 & 0.6035 & \\
                        
                        \hline
                        
                        \textit{A} &                                        & 0.5450 & 0.5450 &  \\
                        \textit{B} & $\lambda=0.10$, $\mu=0.40$, $\nu=0.50$ & 0.6451 & 0.6451 & $B>C>A$ \\
                        \textit{C} &                                        & 0.6035 & 0.6035 & \\
                        
                        \hline
                                        
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[p]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Ranking results for alternatives}
        \label{indices}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Alternative&Value of $\lambda,\mu,\nu$& Value Index&Ambiguity Index&Ranking Order  \\
                        \hline

                        \textit{A} & \multirow{3}{*}{$\lambda=0.10$, $\mu=0.40$, $\nu=0.50$} & 0.5450 & 0.5450 &  \\
                        \textit{B} &                                                         & 0.6451 & 0.6451 & $B>C>A$ \\
                        \textit{C} &                                                         & 0.6035 & 0.6035 & \\
                        
                        \hline
                        
                        \textit{A} & \multirow{3}{*}{$\lambda=0.10$, $\mu=0.40$, $\nu=0.50$} & 0.5450 & 0.5450 &  \\
                        \textit{B} &                                                         & 0.6451 & 0.6451 & $B>C>A$ \\
                        \textit{C} &                                                         & 0.6035 & 0.6035 & \\
                        
                        \hline
                                        
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[p]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Ranking results for alternatives}
        \label{indices}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Alternative&Value of $\lambda,\mu,\nu$& Value Index&Ambiguity Index&Ranking Order  \\
                        \hline

                        \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\itshape}c@{}}A \\ B \\ C \end{tabular} 
                          & $\lambda=0.10$, $\mu=0.40$, $\nu=0.50$ 
                            & \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\itshape}c@{}} 0.5450 \\  0.6451 \\ 0.6035 \end{tabular}
                              & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}0.5450 \\0.6451 \\ 0.6035 \end{tabular}
                                &  $B>C>A$ \\

                        
                        \hline
                        
                        \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\itshape}c@{}}A \\ B \\ C \end{tabular} 
                          & $\lambda=0.10$, $\mu=0.40$, $\nu=0.50$ 
                            & \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\itshape}c@{}} 0.5450 \\  0.6451 \\ 0.6035 \end{tabular}
                              & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}0.5450 \\0.6451 \\ 0.6035 \end{tabular}
                                &  $B>C>A$ \\ 
                        
                        \hline
                                        
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more possible solution, here with use of the `array` and `makecell` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[p]
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
    \caption{Ranking results for alternatives}
    \label{indices}
\[
    \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
    \text{Alternative} 
        &   \text{Value of }\lambda,\;\mu,\;\nu 
            &   \text{Value Index} 
                &   \text{Ambiguity Index}
                    &   \text{Ranking Order}    \\
    \hline
\makecell{A \\ B \\ C}
     &   \lambda=0.10, \mu=0.40, \nu=0.50
        &   \makecell{0.5450\\  0.6451\\ 0.6035}
            &   \makecell{0.5450\\0.6451\\ 0.6035}
                &   B>C>A                                   \\
    \hline
\makecell{A \\ B \\ C}
    &   \lambda=0.10, \mu=0.40, \nu=0.50
        &   \makecell{0.5450\\  0.6451\\ 0.6035}
            &   \makecell{0.5450\\0.6451\\ 0.6035}
                &   B>C>A                                   \\
    \hline
    \end{array}
\]
\end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]