# How to insert the following table in latex beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer

```
\documentclass[10.5pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,mathrsfs,amssymb}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,pstricks,pst-grad}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.6}
\usetheme{focus}
%\usecolortheme{r}
\fontfamily{times new roman}
\justifying
\begin{document}
        \begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{equation*}
            (\tilde{d}_{ij})_{m\times n}=
            \begin{table}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \hline\\
    &C_1&C_2&\dots&C_n\\
    \hline\\
    A_1& \tilde{d}_{11} & \tilde{d}_{12} &\dots& \tilde{d}_{1n}\\
    A_2& \tilde{d}_{21} & \tilde{d}_{22} &\dots& \tilde{d}_{2n}\\
    \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
        A_m& \tilde{d}_{t1} & \tilde{d}_{t2} &\dots& \tilde{d}_{mn}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
            \end{table}
        \end{equation*}
    \end{center} 
    for $i=1,2,\dots,m$ and $j=1,2,\dots,n.$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add the code of your table directly into the question instead of just showing a screenshot of it.

Comment: To start, remove the `table` environment (`\begin{table}` and `\end{table}`)  and replace `tabular` with `array`.

Comment: Most likely unrelated to the issue, but please also clean up your preamble and make sure you don't load packages more than once.

Comment: Also consider, that `beamer` load packages as are `xcolor`, `graphicx`, `hyperref` ... Do you really need so many packages? Many of them as is ˙multicol` hass no sense in `beamer`. Keep in mind, that `beamer` is intended for presentations.

Comment: Got it through removal of table environment and changing tabular with array

Comment: The `center` environment does nothing but adding spurious vertical spacing. An `equation` is already centred.

Comment: This is your 6th question and you did not accept one answer (for the questions for which an answer is provided). Please revisit your old questions and "close" them by accepting existing answers if possible. User **@Zarko** made a similar comment (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568757). In addition, I recommend reading (and follow) the two following links for future questions (to improve the quality of the questions): https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: how to accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you after something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \[
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\Bigl[\tilde{d}_{ij}\Bigr]_{m\times n} = 
\begin{blockarray}{ccc cc}
    & C_1 & C_2 & \dots & C_n       \\
    \begin{block}{c[cc cc]}
A_1 & \tilde{d}_{11}    & \tilde{d}_{12}    & \dots     & \tilde{d}_{1n}    \\
A_2 & \tilde{d}_{21}    & \tilde{d}_{22}    & \dots     & \tilde{d}_{2n}    \\
\vdots
    & \vdots            & \vdots            & \vdots    & \vdots            \\
A_m & \tilde{d}_{t1}    & \tilde{d}_{t2}    & \dots     & \tilde{d}_{mn}    \\
    \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
    \quad\text{for}\quad \makecell[l]{i=1,2,\dots,m \\
                                   j=1,2,\dots,n \;.}
    \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Your document example has few serious flaws:

- equation not need to be inside of `center` environment
- float environment `table` had not to be inserted in equation

In above MWE are corrected these errors.  Also is from your document made MWE (Minimal Working Example) where the preamble of document is reduced only to necessary packages.

Regarding your preamble: it can be significant clean-up. For example to:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

% math
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{mathtools,  % if you really need it, amsmath is loaded by beamer
            amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}
% tables
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
% drawings
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}
% units
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
```